# Not able to save files in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, file-permissions, sudo, file-locking

when I want to save changes in the files I'm modyfing I get following message:

[image]

I click "Save Anyway" and next message shows up:

[image]

I checked and this file is not marked as "Locked"
I also changed permission to all files and folders in project folder to 777 and make myself owner of these files.

The same situation is with newly created projects. I removed XCode and installed the latest version and issue still exists. The same happens on other user accounts.

I also launched XCode with sudo command. There is not problem with saving files but when I run application simulator displays black screen and nothing happens.

The issue occured after guy from it support deleted files from Keychain folder.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Don't change the privileges to 777. Where is your project folder located?

Comment: it's in the folder on my desktop.

Comment: That's strange. I suspected that the folder is somewhere in the local domain. Please check if your desktop folder has the proper privileges: 700

Comment: I changed permission to 700 for desktop folder and still doesn't work.